# Magento brand page based on attribute

Tags: php, magento

I want to be able to have a page on Magento which will be a sub category of the parent category. This page needs to be a brand page but based on the brand attribute with my configuration.

It will need to work kind of the same way the layered navigation would on a normal category page. However I need the page to only show the brands attribute that are assigned to products within the parent category and all other sub categories with images that I will assign to each attribute.

Once you click on one of the brands it would act the same as clickng the brand on a normal category page in the layered navigation.

I have been looking around for a way to do this but can't seem to find any so hoping someone can help out.

Comment: This is really just a work order rather than an SO question, use this plugin - http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/fishpig-s-attribute-splash-pages.html

Comment: Another option is to use https://github.com/magento-hackathon/entitytype-manager. This module isn't finished, but its functionality is enough for your case.

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1:

1. add a new attribute to categories : brand_to_display where you can
   save the brand value
2. add all products to said categories
3. find where the product collection is loaded for the category view
   and chack if brand to display is set, if so add an
   "addAttributeToFilter" on your collection

Solution 2 (better shop performance):

1. add a new attribute to categories : brand_to_display where you can
   save the brand value
2. add an event listener for saving product data in admin area and before save find the categories that have brand_to_display = product->getBrand() and attach product to said categories